# How to package website and database projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project, setup-deployment, web-setup-project

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I have a solution that has 2 SqlServer Database projects and Web application projects. When I build each of these projects they generate SQL scripts and zip files for websites that can then be imported in IIS with MSDeploy.

I want to create a setup project of some sort that will package these sql and zip file outputs and build an installer for me. This installer just needs to copy the files to a particular folder.

I tried creating a Setup project and then adding project outputs from the web and database projects to it, but there doesn't seem to be a way to add the sql/website.zip files instead.

How can I create a setup project that will aggregate these output sql and website zip files?